# Structlog use in modules and for console

Tags: python, structlog

Two related questions about using the production-ready configuration -  https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/performance.html:

i. How to use this configuration across different modules (files)?

ii. How to ensure .info logger output is displayed on the console (terminal) from inside a Class or def function (right now it isn't displaying)?

```
import logging
import structlog

logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(message)s",
    stream=sys.stdout,
    level=logging.INFO,
)

structlog.configure(
    cache_logger_on_first_use=True,
    wrapper_class=structlog.make_filtering_bound_logger(logging.INFO),
    processors=[
        structlog.threadlocal.merge_threadlocal_context,
        structlog.processors.add_log_level,
        structlog.processors.format_exc_info,
        structlog.processors.TimeStamper(fmt="iso", utc=False),
        structlog.processors.JSONRenderer(serializer=orjson.dumps),
    ],
    logger_factory=structlog.BytesLoggerFactory(),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `structlog.configure()`, the configuration is global to your application and valid for all modules.

Please note that your `logging.basicConfig()` has no effect, since your `structlog` config doesn't route the log entries to the standard library.

Your second question needs more context, logging works from functions and classes, there is nothing special about it.

Comment: Returning to this: I have an argparse (CLI) module (A) which calls another module (B) as a subprocess. Doing so, the structlog.configure() configuration from A is lost in B when using logger.exception(e). All is well when the structlog.configure() configuration from A is introduced into B. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Yes, that’s normal. Processes don’t share data unless you use `fork()`.